# Ruby: stack level too deep (SystemStackError) implementing merge sort with inversions counting

Tags: ruby, mergesort

Here is my code.

```
@@inversions = 0
numbers = [very big array]

def merge_sort(array)
  return array if array.size <= 1

  left = array.slice(0, (array.size / 2).round)
  right = array - left
  merge(merge_sort(left), merge_sort(right))
end

def merge(left, right)
  return right if left.empty? # crashes here with stack level too deep
  return left if right.empty?

  if left.first <= right.first
    [left.first] + merge(left[1..-1], right)
  else
    @@inversions += left.size
    [right.first] + merge(left, right[1..-1])
  end
end
```

Can you please tell why it fails? (works on arrays less than ~ 15000 size)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your recursive merge function is probably the reason.  You are going one level deeper in the stack for each element in the array.   A standard merge sort shouldn't go deeper than lg(N).   Try rewriting `merge` to be iterative instead of recursive.

Something like

```
def merge left,right
  a = []
  while !left.empty? and !right.empty?
    if left.first < right.first
       a<<left.shift
    else 
       a<<right.shift
    end
  end
  a + left + right
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You ran out of stack room - obviously - but I think you need to know what this means so here's some theory. I'm based in good old 'assembly' but this is generic problem.

In a computer architecture there is an area of the chip dedicated as a 'stack' which usuaully is a LIFO (last-in first-out) 'scratchpad'. Data is 'pushed' and 'popped' into and off the stack sometimes automagically and sometimes at programmers choice.

There is a finite length to this stack (in *86 overflowing this stack overwrites other special area of the chip (EIP) which is the classic hacking technique for changing progrm flow control but anyway...

In your program everytime recursion or a method call occurs the stack is loaded with the return address of the calling code (so it can return and continue). This is what is causing the stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks, but I know it :) The question was why it happened.

Comment: The "why" is that your final call to `merge` with an array of 15K items called `merge` with 15k-1 items, which called merge with 15K-2 items....